# Codeigniter pagination url use query string

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Default library Pagination of Codeiniter use segment with url like this : `products/list/1`

But , i want config paging use query string.

I have try enable `$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE` but result is `products/list&page=1`

Then , it is not format of query string, i want link paging is : `products/list?page=1`

Please help me ;(

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps:

1. In `application/config/config.php` set:

   `$config['enable_query_strings'] = true;`
2. Again in `application/config/config.php` set:

   `$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";`
3. Change your `.htaccess` to remove the `?` (if present) in the rewrite rule:

   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: If you want to add ? mark then RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L]

Comment: if i set $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO'; page list will be load home page :(

Comment: If you dont then what will happen ?

Comment: If i set $config['uri_protocol'] = PATH_INFO or QUERY_STRING , all other page will load same home page.

Comment: Can you send me your account skype to help me solve this problem :( ?

Comment: sohailyasmin is my skype id

Answer (score 0):

Please define base url like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your path';
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

So your query string is append with above base url like `'path?query_string_of_pagination'`